# How to load a 2nd copy of OneCast with a new license?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, user-account, sudo, root

I am trying to use OneCast to control 10 Xboxes, I have successfully got up to 6 that I can control, I can view all 10, but can't control all 10. The issue I am having is that when I load the app multiple times it loads it under the same User ID, and due to license limitations of the app I can only connect up to 3 Xboxes under a license.

I was able to load 3 more copies of OneCast as a root user giving me access to a total of 6 Xboxes. When I load as another user other than the root user I cannot control the apps with a controller as the bluetooth does not recognize the apps under a different user as the bluetooth connection is ran as a root user which gives it access so far to at least 2 user accounts, the root user and the one that I am currently logged in as. I need to boot up Onecast as the current User I am using but need to have it boot from scratch so I can enter in multiple License keys, giving me access to control all 10 Xboxes.

Here are the commands I have used.

- This command lets me view the connected Xboxes but not control them

  ```
  echo "Password" | sudo -S -u User2/Applications/OneCast#2.app/Contents/MacOS/OneCast
  ```
- This lets me control up to an additional 3 Xboxes for a total of 6

  ```
  echo "Password" | sudo -S /Applications/OneCast#2.app/Contents/MacOS/OneCast
  ```

Is there a way I can edit the .plist file to adjust how OneCast Loads? How do I find where the app's code verifies which user is loading it?

Comment: How about a VM? idk the app or use case at all, but Parallels running another macOS would allow a different user simultaneously.

Comment: @Tetsujin i have thought about that, I tried it with windows, it did not work, just trying to exhaust other options first, not sure if that requires me to buy another license for MacOs? I also do not think it would share the bluetooth across both operating systems, but worth a shot. The goal is to control all 10 using 1 controller, but the controller can only pair with 1 device/user at a time, only able to control 6 Xboxes so far.

Comment: You don't need to buy macOS licenses. As to the rest, I really don't know. You will probably be limited by the particular BT device.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clear violation of their [licensing terms](https://onecast.me/buy/).

[image]

> Our single-user licenses provide access to the software on one or more
>   personally owned machines. Each user needs just one single-user
>   license, regardless of how many machines the software will be used on.
>   Please note that there is also a limit of how many different Xbox One
>   consoles may be used with each license key, so don’t share your
>   license key with others. Licenses found to have been shared will be
>   restricted.

So, based on the behavior of the application you are describing, it is working as described - on a per *user* basis. You can install it on as many Macs as you like, but if the users are different, you're in violation.

I don't advise trying to circumvent this restriction as they seem to imply the ability to disable the software. If you need additional XBox connections or additional functionality, it's best to contact the developer.

Comment: I have purchased 4 license keys, one per each user, I am not trying to add more users per license. Just multiple licenses per mac/user.

Comment: Your use case is apparently different than what the devs envisioned.  Contact them to see if they can implement what you're looking for.  But as it stands, the license it's protection is done per user with a limit on the number of XBoxes.  That's hard coded.